# How to intercept text from the keyboard and format it before it show in the cell?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Part of the program I'm developing stores user-entered phone numbers, so I'd like to format them as they are entered. I've got the NSFormatter working when text is displayed in the cell from stored data, but I don't know how to format a phone number as it's being entered on the keyboard, as in Apple's contacts app.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the delegate of the text field to you controller class, implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and put your formatting code in the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method.